# Float format convert to year month format in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For an excel file in which `date` column is not type of `date` format, so in date `2018.10`, we can see `0` has been omitted and it becomes `2018.1`.

```
date
2018.12
2018.11
2018.1 
2018.9 
2018.8 
2018.7 
2018.6
2018.5
2018.4
2018.3
2018.2
2018.1
```

How can I convert this column to year month format correctly? Thank you.

I try with `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].map('{:.1f}'.format), format='%Y.%m')`, but I get this:

```
8    2018-01-01
9    2018-01-01
10   2018-01-01
11   2018-09-01
12   2018-08-01
13   2018-07-01
14   2018-06-01
15   2018-05-01
16   2018-04-01
17   2018-03-01
18   2018-02-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert values to strings and then to datetimes in first step.

Then correct October - test if previous month is `11`, next is `9` and incorrect is `1`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str), format='%Y.%m')
mo = df['date'].dt.month
mask = mo.shift().eq(11) & mo.eq(1) & mo.shift(-1).eq(9)
df.loc[mask, 'date'] = df.loc[mask, 'date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(month=10)
print (df)
         date
0  2018-12-01
1  2018-11-01
2  2018-10-01
3  2018-09-01
4  2018-08-01
5  2018-07-01
6  2018-06-01
7  2018-05-01
8  2018-04-01
9  2018-03-01
10 2018-02-01
11 2018-01-01
```

Comment: Thank you, but there are two `2018-01-01` you got in result, since `2018.10` has been treated as `2018.1`.

Comment: @ahbon - hmmm, how distinguish `2018.1` with `2018.1` for `2018.10` and `2018.01` ?

Comment: Yeah, the date column in excel is like that. :(

Comment: @ahbon - are data consecutive, always `2018.11` is before `2018.1` ?

Comment: not always consecutive, but `2018.1` below `2018.11` should be `2018.10`, same for other years.

Comment: @ahbon - Answer do 3 checks, I hope it working nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

it might be easiest to fix this in the excel file!  if you've got **a lot** of data (thousands of rows) then maybe it's worth writing code.  code options are:

- look at row above/below and try and infer whether `.1` means be January or October
- ignore the column, if you have data for every month then just make up the correct sequence

Comment: I manually change `2018.1` below `2018.11` to `text` format `2018.10` in excel, but when I use `pd.read_excel` read the file, it still treated as `2018.1`, so I don't how to deal with it.

Comment: the standard approach (recommended by various ISOs) is to use hyphens between date fields.  you can use something like `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","-")` to convert to hyphens, then use the common idiom of copy/"paste formatted" as text.  using dots will always be ambiguous and is something it's just easiest staying away from if you can